# How to dynamically set min-max values into datetimepicker in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, timepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a datetime picker combining datepicker and timepicker [components provided in ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/2.0.2/#/timepicker#min-max) for angular 2. Since the min-max attributes only take values of type Date(), I'm updating them whenever a new date is selected.

But the problem here is the min-max is not restricting the time values if user changes the date. It only works when the new selected value is saved or if the initial value is not changed at all.

**datetimepicker.component.html:**

```
<datepicker
        [ngModel]="selectedDate"
        [showWeeks]="false"
        [startingDay]="1"
        [minDate]="minDate"
        [maxDate]="maxDate"
        (ngModelChange)="storeTempDate($event)">
</datepicker>

<timepicker
        [showMeridian]="false"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedTime"
        [min]="minTime"
        [max]="maxTime">
</timepicker>
```

[image]

**Note:** In the above picture, I have changed the date from *12* to *20*. For *12* it was working but after changing, its not restricting the values(Hours is set to *18* which should not be possible since maxtime is *17* hours).

What am I doing wrong? Any help that can point me in the right direction will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Update:**
This code updates the date for minTime and maxTime according to the date selected.

```
 public storeTempDate(event){
    this._tempSelectedDate = event;
    let dateTimeRange: { "dateRange": { "MinDate": string, "MaxDate": string }, "timeRange": { "MinTime": string, "MaxTime": string } } = JSON.parse(this.expectedRange);

    this.minTime.setDate(this._tempSelectedDate.getDate());
    this.minTime.setMonth(this._tempSelectedDate.getMonth());
    this.minTime.setFullYear(this._tempSelectedDate.getFullYear());
    this.maxTime.setDate(this._tempSelectedDate.getDate());
    this.maxTime.setMonth(this._tempSelectedDate.getMonth());
    this.maxTime.setFullYear(this._tempSelectedDate.getFullYear());

    if (dateTimeRange.dateRange) {
        this._parseDateRange(dateTimeRange.dateRange); //Splits the dateRange and sets date to this.minDate & this.maxDate according to range
    }
    if (dateTimeRange.timeRange) {
        this._parseTimeRange(dateTimeRange.timeRange); //Splits the timeRange and sets Hours and Minutes to this.minTime and this.maxTime according to range
    }
 }
```

**Versions that I use:**

- Angular: 2.4.10
- ngx-bootstrap: 1.9.1

Comment: can you try changing [ngModel]="selectedDate" to [(ngModel)]="selectedDate", it must fix your problem.

Comment: Can you give the initial values for `maxTime` and `maxDate`

Comment: @BinaryPatrick initial maxTime is 'Mon Mar 12 2018 08:30:05' maxDate is currentDate + 100000

Comment: @chnselim I tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: In your post you say `I'm updating them whenever a new date is selected.`. Can you elaborate on how you are updating them when a new date is chosen. Can you show the relevant component code as well?

Comment: @BinaryPatrick I have updated the question with the code you asked.